# bitbucket git pull origin master

Tags: git, deployment, ubuntu-14.04, bitbucket

I use git pull for deployment to my server (ubuntu 14.04). I have multiple sites which I use this for. If pull more than three sites in under a minute it seems to timeout for about 3 mins before I can do another pull on any site. Is there some setting or configuration that would cause this.

```
git pull origin master
```

I sudo su to switch to each user before I run the pull. I also tried just run the command as one user 3 times under a minute and has the same problem without switching users.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot speak to specifics for bitbucket, but many commercial hosting sites throttle speed based on how much you pay.  I also found: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/rate-limits-668173227.html

Comment: I was not aware of that thank you. It feels like I should be well under those limits but I will double check. That is good to know.

Comment: It seems to work if I wait about 15-30 seconds between each pull. If I go under that time frame it blocks subsequent pulls for about 3-5 minutes.